# Primefaces problema ao converter um Enum

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou com problemas para converter um enum fiz uma classe para converter
só que na hora de subtemer o formulário acontece o seguinte erro:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
No enum constant br.com.modelo.enumerados.Situacao.Bloqueada
```

Enum:

```
    public enum Situacao{   
         L("Livre"), B("Bloqueada");
        
        private final String nome;
        
        Situaca(String nome){
            this.nome = nome;
        }
    
        public String getNome() {
            return nome;
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return this.nome;
        }
        
        public static SituacaoPosicao getSituacao(String valor){
            for(Situacao st : Situacao.values()){
                if(st.nome.equals(valor)){
                    return st;
                }
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    
    }
```

Converter:

```
    @FacesConverter("situacaoConverter")
    public class SituacaoConverter implements Converter{
    
        @Override
        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
                if (value != null) {
                    return Situacao.valueOf(value);
                }
    
                return null;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
            if (value != null && value instanceof Situacao) {
                return ((Situacao) value).getNome();
            }
            return null;
        }
    
    }
```

Página XHTML:

```
   <h:form id="formularioAlteracaoCarro">
         
            <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true">
                    <p:autoUpdate />
                </p:messages>
            
        <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
            
            <div class="ui-g-12">
                
                <div class="card card-w-title">
                    <h1>Cadastrar carro</h1>
                    
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank form-group" id="formDadosBox">
                        
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="cbboxBox" value="#{carroMng.carro.box}" 
                                         converter="#{boxConverter}" required="true" 
                                         requiredMessage="#{msg.boxObrigatorio}"
                                      immediate="true">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg.optionSelecioneBox}"/>
                            <f:selectItems value="#{carroMng.listaBoxes}" var="box"
                                        itemValue="#{box}" itemLabel="#{box}"/>
                         </p:selectOneMenu>
                        
                    </p:panelGrid>
                    
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank form-group" id="formDadosSituacao">
                        <h:panelGroup>
                            <p:outputLabel for="radioSituacao" value="#{msg.labelSituacao}" />
                            <p:selectOneRadio layout="responsive" columns="2" id="radioSituacao" 
                                              value="#{carroMng.carro.carro.situacao}" 
                                            converter="#{situacaoConverter}" 
                                             required="true" 
                                            requiredMessage="#{msg.situacaoObrigatoria}">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{carroMng.listarSituacoesAlteracao}" var="carrosituacao"
                                               itemValue="#{carrosituacao}" itemLabel="#{carrosituacao.nome}"/>
                            </p:selectOneRadio>
                            
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                    
                     <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank form-group">
                         <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-save" 
                                        value="#{msg.botaoSalvar}" oncomplete="PF('confirmacaoConclusao').show()"
                                        process="@form" update=":formularioAlteracaoCarro:confirmacaoDialog"
                                        title="#{msg.salvar}"/>  
                         <p:commandButton icon=" ui-icon-closethick" action="#{carroMng.cancelar()}" 
                                     value="#{msg.botaoCancelar}" immediate="true"
                                     title="#{msg.cancelar}"/>
                        
                    </p:panelGrid>
                    
                </div>
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
            
            <p:confirmDialog header="#{msg.mensagemConcluir}" 
                             message="Deseja realmente concluir"
                             widgetVar="confirmacaoConclusao" id="confirmacaoDialog">
                <p:commandButton value="#{msg.textoSim}" oncomplete="PF('confirmacaoConclusao').hide();"
                                 action="#{carroMng.concluirAlteracaoLote()}" process="@form"
                        update=":formularioAlteracaoCarro:formDadosSituacao :formularioAlteracaoCarro:formDadosBox" id="yesButton" />
                <p:button value="#{msg.textoNao}" onclick="PF('confirmacaoConclusao').hide(); return false;" />
            </p:confirmDialog>
            
            
    </h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rodrigo,

Isso acontece porque `br.com.modelo.enumerados.Situacao.Bloqueada` não existe. O que existe é `br.com.modelo.enumerados.Situacao.B`.

Na sua lógica, você não deve manipular o valor do Enumeration, mas sim o Enumeration em si. Use somente o valor `String` do Enumeration para imprimir.

Você já tem um método criado para isso, o `getSituacao`. Então você deveria usar no método abaixo em vez de `valueOf()`:

```
  @Override
  public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
     if (value != null) {
         return Situacao.getSituacao(value);
     }
    
     return null;
  }
```

Comment: Fiz desta forma o erro persiste ao submeter o formulário:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at br.com.modelo.enumerados.SituacaoPosicao.getSituacaoPosicao(Situacao.java:32)
 at br.com.converter.SituacaoConverter.getAsObject(SituacaoConverter.java:19)

Comment: qual é a linha 32?

Comment: throw new IllegalArgumentException(); na classe Situação

Comment: Acabei de rodar o código na minha máquina e funciona. Seu método tem alguns problemas de compilação que vou arrumar para você.

Comment: Isso significa que o valor não é o correto. Troque a linha 32 por:  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Valor não existe = " + valor);

Comment: Inclui o formulário todo para verificação pois, ao subter também não está recuperando os dados informados....

Comment: aí já é outro problema. Vamos tentar verificar o problema do Enum, que faz parte da sua pergunta. Você trocou a linha linha 32 por: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Valor não existe = " + valor); ?

Comment: deu o seguinte erro:
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Can't set property 'situacao' on class 'br.com.modelo.Carro' to value 'Bloqueada'.

Comment: Rodrigo, essa é outra excessão em vez do IllegalArgumentException. O problema anterior foi resolvido, se sim, clique em Resolvida a pergunta. E aí deve-se avaliar por que seu código não estão funcionando. Esse é uma nova exceção e não a que você perguntou.

Comment: Entendi o erro depois que alterou para a sua solução não conseguiu setar o valor B ou L no enum gerando o erro. O problema está em setar esse valor que deveria ser ou B ou L quando submete o formulário